# How to get url params when using hash in url

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, prototypejs, hashcode

I am using AJAX with hash in URL with prototypejs.

When I use following URL:

http://example.com/#/example/104?v=0&d=a&rpp=10

```
print_r( $_GET );  // output: array()
```

When I use following URL:

http://example.com/example/104?v=0&d=a&rpp=10

```
print_r( $_GET );  // output: Array ( [v] => 0 [d] => a [rpp] => 10 )
```

So my question why I am not able to get URL params when using hash in URL. How can I get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part after the `#` doesn't get sent to the server.

(Its original purpose was to refer to a piece of the document, so that a URL could load a document and then scroll to a particular section.  You can see how sending it to the server would be irrelevant in that case.)

Comment: rewite your `#` with something, depends on your app structure

Comment: ok. I am doing `parent.location.hash = url;` after completing ajax request. (here `url` is complete url passed to ajax request function).. How can I change this to remove `#` from URL without refreshing whole page...

Comment: @Awan: You can't.  If you want to send the piece of the URL after the `#` to the server, you'll need to send it via an AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

Form your request like this:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/#/example/104?v=0&d=a&rpp=10';
new Ajax.Request(url, {
    parameters: url.match(/\?(.*)/)[1]
});
```